# GPS, adding a function and returning a value from locationManager class

Tags: android, class, gps, locationmanager

I'm making a basic GPS. I want to put the location listener class in a seperate file and add a few functions, it doesn't seem possible. I get this error when i try to get the return value out of the getLatitude: //The method getLongitude is undefined for the type Location Listener.

Is there a way to make the class my own class?
Code:

```
import com.google.android.maps.*;
//import com.learntoprogram.android.GeoLocationActivity.mylocationlistener;
import Maps.GeoLocation.Google.mylocationlistener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsGeoLocationActivity extends MapActivity {

    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

        mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        double lat = ll.getLongitude(); //The method getLongitude is undefined for the type Location Listener
        double longi = -96.666;

        GeoP = new GeoPoint ((int) (lat *1E6), (int) (longi *1E6));
        mControl = mapV.getController();
        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);

    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Class code:
mylocationmanager.java

```
package Maps.GeoLocation.Google;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
double pLong;
double pLat;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null)
        {
            pLong = location.getLongitude();
            pLat = location.getLatitude();



        }
        else
        {
            pLong = 40.8;
            pLat = -96.666;
        }



    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return pLong;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return pLat;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you're showing us the actual code. The code here doesn't compile because of 'double lat = ll.getLongitude();'. Can you append a stack trace please?

Comment: Reno's answer should have worked. Try using the fully qualified name of your class myLocationListener in case you have put it in some named folder or something where the runtime cannot find the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of this line

```
LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
```

change it to

```
mylocationlistener ll = new mylocationlistener();
```

Comment: tried it already doesn't work i get this error:
mylocationListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Your package name looks fishy Maps.GeoLocation.Google;
 change it to something else

Comment: changed it to com.learningandroid.locationm and still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Change `LocationListener ll` to `mylocationlistener ll`

as the methods `getLongitude()` and `getLatitude()` belong to the class `mylocationlistener`

Comment: tried it already doesn't work i get this error:
mylocationListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Weird. Add `import Maps.GeoLocation.Google.*;` to `MapsGeoLocationActivity.java`.

Comment: Shouldn't `mylocationmanager.java` actually be `mylocationlistener.java`?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have an instance of `LocationListener` which haven't such methods.

Also, it may be useful to create an interface of callback to do something like this:

```
MyLocationListener = new LocationListener(
    new Callback() {
       public void onSuccess() {
          // Do something inside caller class
       }
    }
);
```

So, to do this you must have an appropriate constructor

EDIT: LocationListener is async, so it is a bad practise to get values syncroniously